# Wrapping eloquent model to another class causes exceeded nesting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm using Laravel 5.5. I wrote a wrapper that takes an Eloquent model and wraps it to an `Entity` class and each model has own wrapper. Assume, the User has many products and a Product belongs to one user. When wrapping, I need to get products of a user and pass them to product wrapper to wrap them into the product entities. In the product wrapper, I need to get user owner of this product to wrap it to the user entity. So again, In the user wrapper, I need user products!, and this creates an infinite loop.

**EntityWrapper:**

```
abstract class EntityWrapper
{
    protected $collection;
    protected $entityClass;
    public $entity;

    public function __construct($collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->entity = $this->buildEntity();
    }

    protected function buildEntity()
    {
        $tempEntity = new $this->entityClass;

        $Entities = collect([]);

        foreach ($this->collection as $model) {
            $Entities->push($this->makeEntity($tempEntity, $model));
        }

        return $Entities;
    }

    abstract protected function makeEntity($entity, $model);
}
```

**UserEntityWrapper:**

```
class UserEntityWrapper extends EntityWrapper
{
    protected $entityClass = UserEntity::class;

    protected function makeEntity($userEntity, $model)
    {
        $userEntity->setId($model->user_id);
        $userEntity->setName($model->name);

        // set other properties of user entity...

        //--------------- relations -----------------
        $userEntity->setProducts((new ProductEntityWrapper($model->products))->entity);

        return $userEntity;
    }
}
```

**ProductEntityWrapper:**

```
class ProductEntityWrapper extends EntityWrapper
{
    protected $entityClass = ProductEntity::class;

    protected function makeEntity($productEntity, $model)
    {
        $productEntity->setId($model->product_id);
        $productEntity->setName($model->name);

        // set other properties of product entity...

        //--------------- relations -----------------
        $productEntity->setUser((new UserEntityWrapper($model->user))->entity);

        return $productEntity;
    }
}
```

**UserEntity:**

```
class UserEntity
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $products;
    //... other properties

    public function setProducts($products)
    {
         $this->products = $products;
    }

    // other getters and setters...
}
```

When I wnat to get user entities by calling `(new UserEntityWrapper(User::all()))->entity`, It causes infinite loop. So, how can I prevent the nesting call to relationship between models? Thanks to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. As in each wrapper class, I used the dynamic property to get the relationship collection, in addition to imposing extra queries, this causes lazy loading. So, before passing the model collection into each wrapper, the necessary relationship model is retrieved and each wrapper firstly checks the existence of relationship using method `getRelations()` (that returns an array of available relations). If intended relationship is available, the collection of relationship models is passed into the proper wrapper class.

**UserEntityWrapper:**

```
class UserEntityWrapper extends EntityWrapper
{
    protected $entityClass = UserEntity::class;

    protected function makeEntity($userEntity, $model)
    {
        $userEntity->setId($model->user_id);
        $userEntity->setName($model->name);

        // set other properties of user entity...

        //--------------- relations -----------------
        $relations = $model->getRelations();

        $products = $relations['products'] ?? null;
        if ($products) {
            $userEntity->setProducts((new ProductEntityWrapper($products))->entity);
        }

        return $userEntity;
    }
}
```

And, a similar functionality is used for the other wrappers.